# SqlAlchemy - no foreign keys linking these tables. Past created table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a problem with sqlalchemy which is stopping me from making any ground. I've created other tables with relationships but this one seems to not work because of some faulty tables I made previously. The code below is the test and when I run it I get the error I've pasted below the code:

```
import os 
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class X(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'x2'
    pid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    color = Column(String(4), nullable=False)
    player = relationship('Y')

class Y(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'y2'
    name = Column(String(16), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    champion = Column(String(16), nullable=False)
    kills = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    deaths = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('x2.pid'))



engine = create_engine('postgresql://db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)



from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
#from lol_db_setup import Base, Match, Team, Player

engine = create_engine('postgresql://heyfinn:lolpassword@leagueoflegendsdb.c3jpkci5dhiy.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/leagueoflegendsdb')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = DBSession()
teamEntry = X(pid=1234, color = 'red')
newEntry = Y(name='heyfinn', id=622740, champion = 'Zac', kills=10, deaths = 0, team_id= 1234)
session.commit()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-56c613d76617> in <module>()
      8 DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
      9 session = DBSession()
---> 10 teamEntry = X(id=1234, color = 'red')
     11 newEntry = Y(name='heyfinn', id=622740, champion = 'Zac', kills=10, deaths = 0, team_id= 1234)
     12 session.commit()

<string> in __init__(self, **kwargs)
InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 
'Mapper|Match|match'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Match.team - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  
Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

So I gather the problem must be with a table 'match' and it's foreign key that I'd created earlier. How can I get rid of this remnant of the 'match' table so I can just build these other tables?

Comment: To update, I've made another instance of the above that works but I still don't understand why that error occured. I expect it's just a lack of knowledge about 'mappers'.

Comment: When you declare a class to derive from `Base`, SQLAlchemy will keep track of it so that it can later initialize it. You need to create a fresh `Base` to make SQLAlchemy "forget" previously-defined classes. Since you're running in an IPython console, I assume you just declared `X` and `Y` on the same `Base` as `Match`.

Comment: Aha! Gee thanks. I guess I should have just paid attention while reading the docs.